# Mongoose complex query with nested Or's/And's

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm currently stuck on trying to figure out a certain problem using Mongoose with Node.js and MongoDb. I have records in my mongodb plan collection that have the plan date split among 3 different fields, one for storing year, one for month, and one for day - all Number fields. For instance, the date 7/4/2014 would be stored like so:

```
_id: fjewifjweifja...
Name: "test plan name"
PlanDateYear: 2014
PlanDateMonth: 7
PlanDateDay: 4
```

I am trying to construct a mongoose query that will return me all the plan records that exist between a specified start and end date range. I have the query working for getting plans between start and end date range if all the plans dates happen to be in the same year, however if some of the plans dates cross over into another year then the mongoose query logic gets all whacky. Is there some concise way to do this within the constraints of having the fields in the plan collection: PlanDateYear, PlanDateMonth, and PlanDateDay?

Thanks so much for your help! I've been stuck on this for awhile now :(

Here's my current query:

```
Plan.find({
                    'user': req.user.id,
                    "$or" : [
                        {
                            'planDateMonth': startDateMonth,
                            "$and" : [
                                { "planDateDay" : {$gte: startDateDay} }
                                ,{'planDateMonth': {$ne: endDateMonth}}
                                //,{'planDateYear': {$gte: startDateYear}}

                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            'planDateMonth': endDateMonth,
                            "$and" : [
                                { "planDateDay" : {$lte: endDateDay} }
                                ,{'planDateMonth': {$ne: startDateMonth}}

                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            'planDateMonth': {$ne: endDateMonth},
                            "$and" : [
                                {'planDateMonth': {$ne: startDateMonth}},
                                {'planDateMonth': {$lte: endDateMonth, $gte: startDateMonth}},
                                {'planDateDay': {$lte: endDateDay, $gte: startDateDay}}

                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            'planDateMonth': endDateMonth,
                            "$and" : [
                                {'planDateMonth': startDateMonth},
                                {'planDateDay': {$lte: endDateDay, $gte: startDateDay}}

                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            )
              .exec(function (err, plans) {
                if (err) return next(err);

                else {
        //do stuff
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason these aren't stored as dates?

Comment: to be honest, i was running into a lot of issues storing javascript dates, even when stored as UTC. Plan dates that were supposed to be a certain day would end up as the previous or next day depending on the remote server location that my website is hosted (using heroku and I notice the website was a server in a far away time zone). I really only was able to get consistent dates from the server when i stored year, month, and day as separate fields and as ints, and then did comparisons on those 3 fields when pulling specific dates from the DB.

Comment: There are ways to work around that. I tend to store all dates as UTC for comparison purposes. It's also possible to store dates as YYYYMMDD and still have very simple comparison. Basically separate year month and day is going to be the most difficult to query against.

Comment: yeah, you're totally right. What are your thoughts on storing the date as miliseconds using date.getTime() and then doing comparisons on that, since i just need to pull dates between a specific start and end date range? So then, the mongoose query would be: 'planDateAsMili': {$gte: startDateAsMili, $lte: endDateAsMili}

Comment: are you able to add your comment as an answer and i'll mark it as an answer? Following your advice solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would find a way to work with Mongo Dates, or use integer to represent dates (YYYYMMDD) since simple math comparisons work as expected on them.